# EXEC sp_executesql @sql

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking for help. When I run `EXEC sp_executesql @sql`, I'm not getting output in `@jsonOutput` where output consists of dynamic columns.

I want to get output to a table/json format. I tried below code...

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @jsonOutput NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = ' SELECT cf.mid, cf.sordt, d.*, x.*
             FROM #tempdrill d
             INNER JOIN b.conf cf ON d.dd = cf.sordt
                                  AND d.hikey = cf.hkeyperson
                                  AND (SELECT dm FROM #tempp) = cf.mid
             INNER JOIN ' + @pt + 'x ON CAST(x.id AS VARCHAR(100)) = cf.id
           ' FOR JSON AUTO';

-- Execute the dynamic SQL and store the result in a variable
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@jsonOutput NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @jsonOutput OUTPUT;

-- Print the JSON result
SELECT @jsonOutput;
```

Comment: ...is there a reason you can't do the JSON transformation in application-code?

Comment: You don't assign your variable to anything. It should be something like `select @json = (select... Your json query) `

Comment: The query you've given us isn't valid, and it also looks like it's open to injection attacks

Comment: Aside... whitespace matters. If we assume for a moment that your `@pt` variable holds a table name `schema.Foo` then the resultant SQL will cause errors at `...INNER JOIN schema.Foox ON CAST(...` because there's no table named `schema.Foox` and the `x` aliases used elsewhere are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the output variable from within dynamic SQL.

```sql
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @jsonOutput NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = '
SELECT @jsonOutput = (
    SELECT cf.mid, cf.sordt, d.*, x.*
    FROM #tempdrill d
    INNER JOIN b.conf cf
        ON d.dd = cf.sordt
       AND d.hikey = cf.hkeyperson
       AND cf.mid IN (SELECT dm FROM #tempp)
    INNER JOIN ' + @pt + 'x ON CAST(x.id AS VARCHAR(100)) = cf.id
    FOR JSON AUTO
);
';

-- Execute the dynamic SQL and store the result in a variable
EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
    N'@jsonOutput NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT',
    @jsonOutput = @jsonOutput OUTPUT;

-- Print the JSON result
SELECT @jsonOutput;
```

However it's unclear why you need an output variable at all if you are just selecting it. You can select directly out of dynamic SQL.

```sql
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = '
SELECT (
    SELECT cf.mid, cf.sordt, d.*, x.*
    FROM #tempdrill d
    INNER JOIN b.conf cf
        ON d.dd = cf.sordt
       AND d.hikey = cf.hkeyperson
       AND cf.mid IN (SELECT dm FROM #tempp)
    INNER JOIN ' + @pt + 'x ON CAST(x.id AS VARCHAR(100)) = cf.id
    FOR JSON AUTO
);
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```